# How to get to recovery mode if grub screen does not appear?

Tags: ubuntu, grub, vmware

I cannot login my Ubuntu12.04 (which is VM running on OSX using VMWARE FUSION 6) because I have changed permission of `/tmp` for some purpose before rebooting the machine.

Thus I tried to boot Ubuntu in recovery mode by pressing `shift` key while booting the machine (in order to change the permission of `/tmp`), but it was not possible because no grub screen appears while booting.

How can I get into recovery mode if grub does not appear?

Comment: Press the [Shift] at initial boot should bring up the `grub` menu.

If that fails, then boot your VM with the installation ISO image or any recovery CD image.  Mount you root partition and fix `/tmp`.

Comment: If you can't get a grub screen the problem has nothing to do with the permissions on `/tmp`.

Comment: @kolar If you are able to boot, you should check the timeouts in `/etc/default/grub`

Comment: Just boot into the live session in the same way as when you installed, mount the Ubuntu drives and fix them.

Comment: My installation disk was Ubuntu 10, but I upgraded that thus it's Ubuntu 12.04. Booting VM with installation ISO image (Ubuntu 10) does not show my Ubuntu 12.04. It just try to install Ubuntu 10.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a situation tailor-made for an iPXE rescue. Essentially you boot your virtual machine not from its own virtual disk filesystem but using bootstrap files retrieved over the internet. In practice its nearly identical to booting from a Live ISO image on a removable drive and once the environment has finished booting you will be able to mount your virtual disk and effect any needed repairs.

You can find the instructions for replacing VMware's included PXE ROM with an iPXE ROM [here](https://ipxe.org/howto/vmware) (my best results with this process have been with VMware set to emulate the Intel e1000e network adapter, but they all should work). With the ROM file replaced and the .vmx file for your virtual machine edited as described, open VMware Fusion, select the virtual machine in question and verify in the GUI that the network adapter model you set in the vmx file is active and in Bridged mode.

[image]

With that settled, click <kbd>OK</kbd> to exit the Settings window then click the green Play button in the main Fusion window to start your VM.

As soon as its window appears, begin pressing the <kbd>F2</kbd> key on your keyboard at roughly one second intervals until you're presented with the Firmware Setup menu, it may take a few cycles of shutting the virtual machine down and starting it again to get the timing right. You'll know you got it when something like this appears:

[image]

The Firmware Setup menu is navigated using only the keyboard, so tap the <kbd>➔</kbd> key until you reach the Boot settings, then the <kbd>⬆</kbd>/<kbd>⬇</kbd> so that the "Network boot from ..." option is highlighted, then finally the <kbd>+</kbd> key as many times as are required to move it to the top of the list so it becomes the first boot device. With that done, press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to confirm the new boot configuration and the virtual machine should naturally restart and put them into action.

Once it begins the boot process again, it's important to pay close attention to the console output. Typically booting via PXE requires a local server somewhere on the network to supply the bootstrapped environment files, but the specification also provides a `chain` command that takes a URL as an argument which is certainly the simplest method to make this work. To use the chain command you need to watch for a message shown during the early stages of the boot process which looks like this:

```
 iPXE -- Open Source Network Boot Firmware -- http://ipxe.org
  Features: HTTP iSCSI DNS TFTP AoE FCoE TFTP COMBOOT ELF PXE PXEXT
  
  Press Ctrl-B for the iPXE command line...
```

Naturally that's your cue to mash the key combination it specifies to switch to the command line!

(*It's usually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> but I've seen other key combinations once or twice*)

The desired outcome is that as a result of everything you've done, you will now see something which closely resembles:

```
iPXE>
```

Congratulations, you're in the home stretch. The final step is to get an IP address from your network appliance and point your virtual machine at the server belonging to the [Netboot.xyz Project](https://netboot.xyz/booting/ipxe/). In summary, you need to issue two separate commands at the iPXE command line prompt. They are:

- `dhcp`
- `chain --autofree https://boot.netboot.xyz/menu.ipxe`

In a matter of seconds you should be presented with a smorgasbord of Linux distributions' Live Images to boot into as well as a large number of popular "rescue discs" which can be booted into as well. See?

[image]

It should also be noted, in case you encounter any difficulties, that the Netboot.xyz team has their own [recommended process](https://netboot.xyz/booting/vmware/) for using iPXE to access their service from within VMware that differs from what I've just detailed here, though I've not found it to be as reliable in my own experiences. In addition, all of the iPXE commands that you can use on the command line besides `dhcp` and `chain` are neatly detailed with examples [here](https://ipxe.org/cmd).

Best of luck to you!

---

**Note:** The above iPXE commands assume that you're using a UEFI configuration for your virtual machine as has become increasingly widespread in recent years. If I'm in error about that and you're configured as a BIOS boot process, the final command will need to be a bit different; use this chain command instead of the one above: `chain --autofree https://boot.netboot.xyz/ipxe/netboot.xyz.lkrn`